# The "Why won't my helloworld.png compile?" question is on-topic

Tags: support, scope, closed-questions, historical-lock

[Why is this program erroneously rejected by three C++ compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers)

Current status, which I believe is incorrect:

> locked by Will Jul 2 '13 at 18:08
>
> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.

It's a legitimate question with a good answer with a proper citation. It is not a mistake someone might plausibly make, although it is an example of an input that if one were to consider, one might wonder why the standard and the compilers will reject it.

The question is asked in a roleplaying voice. If we played dumb and thought the OP were serious, it would be a perfectly legitimate question. If we acknowledge the roleplay, it is a perfectly good didactic exercise.

It is also a pristine example of how to ask a good question. Researched on multiple compilers. I actually think it's a little troubling to reject a question that is perfectly compliant and very educational because of further unwritten community standards. It just reinforces the idea that StackOverflow is secretly arbitrary and fickle.

So suggest unlocking it.

Comment: You don't have to wonder or debate that question.  It simply doesn't meet the requirements as clearly laid out in the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).  And it's fun, and therefore should be snuffed out with ruthless determination.

Answer (score 14):

It's an April Fools joke that has long outlived its asking date. It's very clever, but there is no reason at all for *any* community to pretend that April Fools jokes, or any other obviously and deliberately nonstandard material, must be treated with the same careful respect as what the community is *actually* about. (Unless it's a comedian's forum. Humor is serious business.) Jokes are second-class citizens, and there is no sense in making an elaborate and precisely binding set of regulations for allowable trolling of SO. Those would only be carefully exploited (in the same vein as "I'm not touching you!", but with fractionally more cunning and eloquence).

Any real assertion based on this question that SO is "secretly arbitrary and fickle" is either sadly lacking in discernment, or deliberate propaganda, and should be ruthlessly ignored.

Comment: Is the answer quoting the standard made up too? I've been under the impression I've learned something from this Q&A and TBH I thought it was a good question, I mean it's certainly not the case I understood the answer or realized the language spec *thought* of this, and in my career I've tended to prefer working with engineers who come up with interesting corner cases to specs and programs (like compilers), and are curious, and I don't agree that the April Fools origin of the question negates any of this.

Comment: If the answer quoting spec is fabricated then the question clearly needs to be deleted. April Fools pranks aren't supposed to trick people on arbitrary days of the year for the next decade.

Comment: Beyond that, I'm clearly outvoted, but in my original question and above comment outlined very good reasons the community should carefully respect this nonstandard material which clearly directly contributes to what this community is actually about, which includes learning programming. The question is also clearly not an example of trolling, which is mean-spirited. I guess my assertion is propaganda in the interest of learning programming but beyond that I don't know what you are talking about in that portion of your answer.

Comment: @djechlin: Historical locks are for questions that would normally be deleted, except that they managed to gather enough attention that it seems a shame to simply wipe them out. Therefore, it's the three or so serious answers that make this locked instead of deleted.

Comment: @djechlin: My last paragraph is to handle the type of person who uses these questions as "proof" in their blog rants that SO is filled with nothing but soup Nazis. (It is not really meant for you.)

Comment: I know the point of historical locks, and the fact that the serious answers popped up is exactly how SO is supposed to work :/ https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/ that's why this is so frustrating to me, like is the fact that a funny question *also* was a serious question really too abstract for us brainy pointer-wielding programmers to understand. The OP had a point, at a technical level I clearly don't expect a compiler to OCR a .png, but I thought the specs were thorough, where do they prohibit it? That's a compelling and insightful question.

Comment: If you added the sentence to it "Clearly I don't expect a compiler to perform OCR on an image, and obviously it doesn't from these thorough examples, but I would expect the spec to cover this case. Where do they?" Yet I think the average reader can be reasonably expected to infer that voice, as a byproduct we hopefully enjoy the question but enjoyment is not a close-reason.

Comment: The question also uses humor to *perfectly* explain *exactly* what an on-topic question looks like here. Why would we immediately follow this beautiful educational opportunity to learn how to use SO with "Just kidding! This is off topic, please disregard." BTW I'm going to roll up my comments here to an answer on the other question.

Comment: @djechlin: I cannot agree that this question in any way typifies a *good*, on-topic question. It's a very careful feigning of inveterate ignorance to a degree that is remarkably difficult, in real questions, to cure at all. SO is not designed to cope with the degree of computer illiteracy that can sincerely confuse an image of text with actual text. "Why don't computers do things the way people do?" is certainly instructive enough, but far, far too broad a topic in general.

Comment: you can't go from a specific question to a general topic the question came from then say the question was too general. "How do you write code?" is also too general. We close the questions that ask this directly. We don't close questions that are specific instances of this category. And yet the answers cured the (fake) illiteracy! And it's not illiterate to expect there to be a good answer to that question and it's on-topic to want to know why compilers do or do not do the things they do. Also, compilers are free to implement OCR during input, so they may do things the way people do.

Comment: ...and the entire field of machine learning is about how computers can do things the way people do, and machine learning is all else being equal on topic. In this case OCR is the machine learning component in this question.